# HTTPBuilder & Session ID

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder

I have the following code to connect to a REST API service, authenticate, retrieve a session ID then make further requests passing the session ID to authenticate. The initial request works and I get a HTTP 200 OK plus the session ID in the response, however when I try to make a second request passing the session ID in the header, I get

**Caught: groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Bad Request**

I know the script can be written much better with the use of classes and try / catch etc. I am still learning both java and groovy so I start by just trying to do everything within the same class.

Any help much appreciated.

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.URIBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*

def url = 'https://1.1.1.1/web_api/'
def uri = new URIBuilder(url)

String CHKPsid

uri.path = 'login'
def http = new HTTPBuilder(uri)
http.ignoreSSLIssues()


http.request(POST,JSON ) { req ->
headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
body = [
        "user":"username",
        "password":"password"
]
    response.success = { resp, json ->
        println (json)
        CHKPsid = (json.sid)
        println "POST Success: ${resp.statusLine}"
    }
}

uri.path = 'show-changes'
http.request(POST,JSON ) { req ->
headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
headers.'X-chkp-sid' = '${CHKPsid}'
body = [
        "from-date"   : "2017-02-01T08:20:50",
        "to-date"     : "2017-10-21"
  ]
    response.success = { resp, json ->
        println (json)
        println "POST Success: ${resp.statusLine}"
  }
}
```

Comment: `400 Bad Request` means that your request is incorrect. Try reading server response first to see what is wrong with the request you are executing (REST API should return a JSON object that describes the error).

Comment: Thanks @SzymonStepniak. The failure response is as follows **[code:generic_err_invalid_syntax, message:Login request message processing failed]
POST Failure: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**. The code I suspect is wrong is were I try to pass the value of the session ID assigned variable(CHKPsid) into the request header as X-chkp-sid. Does this look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_string_interpolation) does not work with single (or triple single quotes). When groovy will evaluate `'${CHKPsid}'` (single quotes), its value will be `${CHKPsid}` (this string). In order to use the *value* of the variable, you should use double quotes: `"${CHKPsid}"` or simply just the variable: `headers.'X-chkp-sid' = CHKPsid`.

So the output of this:

```
String CHKPsid = "abc123"
println '${CHKPsid}'
println "${CHKPsid}"
```

will be:

```
${CHKPsid}
abc123
```

In order to quickly test what the server receives, you can use [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org/) or [requestb.in](https://requestb.in/)

Comment: Thanks. 'headers.`x-chkp-sid' = CHKPsid` works and passes the sid correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So as well as the correct assignment of the value of the session ID, I found that calling the same HTTPbuilder - `http.request` the second time even with a change of uri, header and body was the problem. The listening server still saw this as part of the same login API call. My workaround / resolution was to define a 2nd HTTPbuilder with a different name and this now works. I'm interested to know if this is normal behaviour and how others approach this. Thanks.